# What does |_| mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

This is a snippet taken from `gem prawn`. What does that `|_|` mean in the second line?

```
def canvas(&block)
      init_bounding_box(block, :hold_position => true) do |_|
        # Canvas bbox acts like margin_box in that its parent bounds are unset.
        @bounding_box = BoundingBox.new(
          self, nil, [0, page.dimensions[3]],
          :width => page.dimensions[2],
          :height => page.dimensions[3]
        )
      end
    end
```

I am trying to learn ruby by going through different gems.

Comment: This particular block should receive one parameter and we don’t care about it’s value.

Comment: Sooner or later you might encounter `|*|` syntax—that is the same, but for the block, expecting _any_ vary amount of parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically just throwing away the value. A normal do block would have something like |my_var|